# JavaNullPointer Exception filling an array

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

I am executing this code:

```
 HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                //Web service call
                transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION_BRING_NEEDS, envelope);

                //create SoapPrimitive and obtain response
                resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                int intPropertyCount = resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount();
                strNeeds = new String[intPropertyCount];

                for(int i= 0;i< intPropertyCount; i++)
                {
                    //strNeeds[i]= resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();
                    //Format the information from the web service
                    Object property = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(i);
                    if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
                        SoapObject needsList = (SoapObject) property;
                        strNeeds[i] = needsList.getProperty("Descripcion").toString();
                        strCodeNeeds[i] = needsList.getProperty("Codigo").toString();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                exc = true;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and its braking on this line of code:

```
 strCodeNeeds[i] = needsList.getProperty("Codigo").toString();
```

with the error `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the exception and the `suppressedExceptions = {java.util.Collections$EmptyList@830033977576} = 0`.

I put watches on the "needList" iterating the "For" and it contains this result in `position 0 = anyType{Codigo=3; CodigoClase=1; Descripcion=Acceso a puerto; }`

and the array `strNeeds[i]` is filling correctly.

any idea what is happening? Thanks in advice.

Comment: do sysout of needsList.getProperty("Codigo") and see what you get. My guess is it's null.

Comment: @Susie I do it, and I am getting correctly the value that I need, needsList.getProperty("Codigo").toString() = {java.lang.String@830038562832}"3"

Comment: where did you instantiate `strCodeNeeds`?

Comment: @yaa110 yea that was missing on the tutorial, but was a lot of code  so I realice it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it results a tutorial mistake! they forgot to Initializate the strCodeNeeds,

```
strCodeNeeds = new String[intPropertyCount];
```